# Use CloudFormation Mapping as environment variable for custom resource lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a mapping in CloudFormation template, let us say it is:

```
"Mappings" : {
    "RegionMap" : {
      "us-east-1" : { "Name" : "Aaaa" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "Name" : "Bbbb" }
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass this mapping as an environment variable to the lambda within this template:

```
 "Environment": {
     "Variables": {
           "regions": {
                 "Ref": "RegionMap"
            }
     }
  }
```

But this gives me the error:

> Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource
>   dependencies [RegionMap] in the Resources block of the template

Is any way to make it working?

Comment: Do you want to pass the complete mapping to the Lambda function or only one of the AMIs ?

Comment: Complete mapping. The structure of this mapping is just an example which has no relation to its real contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*CloudFormation* mappings section data is only meant to be extracted using the intrinsic function `Fn::FindInMap`. This means you won't be able to send the whole mapping object as environment variable. Beside, regardless of the context, environment variable are always strings. CloudFormation would have to serialize this object in either json or yaml or another format and that's probably why it won't let you do it.

That being said, you could do this yourself, you could copy the mapping and convert it as a json string (with escaped quotes, etc) and pass the value as an environment variable. Then in your Lambda code you could transform it back to an object.

If your intention was to create a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) with your Lambda function, then you can pass the whole JSON object as a parameter to the resource. For exemple:

```
"AMIInfo": {
  "Type": "Custom::AMIInfo",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["AMIInfoFunction", "Arn"] },
    "RegionMap" : {
      "us-east-1" : { "Name" : "Aaaa" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "Name" : "Bbbb" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But if I want to use this map in several different lambdas within one template?

Comment: If the map is static you could consider hard coding it in your Lambdas. Another solution (read hack) would be to use a CloudFormation parameter (user input) and pass the map as a string, then you could "Ref" it in every Lambda function definition. You could even set the wanted value as the "default" for that parameter. Last solution, if all you really care is code reuse, you could use a tool like https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere and dynamically generate your template while using the same map for each Lambda definition.

Comment: The idea about passing map as a default value for the parameter is very nice. For this particular idea +1 and accepted :) Thanks!